# Get Environment variable from .env file and pass to Dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This seems like a huge oversight on the developers behalf as I can't understand the use case where you don't want the image build to know about .env variables.

I'm running Laravel and I'm access some AWS keys from with a .env file. When I try to build an image via a Dockerfile, the php compsoer autoload fails because one of the classes in my project is trying to instantiate an AWS S3Client (from the php SDK) using the .env variables.

I can't figure out how to pass the environment variables from the .env file to the Dockerfile at all.

So far I've got this, which isn't working on an image build, but of course works file if I'm just running the container

```
resource:
build: 
  context: ../server
  args:
    - AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION}
    - AWS_VERISON=${AWS_VERISON}
    - AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME=${AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME}
    - AWS_S3_CREDENTIALS_SECRET=${AWS_S3_CREDENTIALS_SECRET}
    - AWS_S3_CREDENTIALS_KEY=${AWS_S3_CREDENTIALS_KEY}
env_file: ./variables.env
ports:
  - "8080:80"
depends_on:
  - db
  - nosql
volumes:
  - ../server/app:/var/www/app:ro
```

The Dockerfile, abbreviated because everything else works fine and it's a huge file

```
ARG AWS_REGION
ARG AWS_VERISON
ARG AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME
ARG AWS_S3_CREDENTIALS_SECRET
ARG AWS_S3_CREDENTIALS_KEY
```

How can I pass the variables to the build file?

EDIT:

Here's the section of the docerfile that runs the composer script and then creates the entry point to the container:

```
RUN composer dumpautoload && \
php artisan clear-compiled --no-interaction && \
php artisan optimize --no-interaction

ENTRYPOINT  php artisan config:cache && \
        supervisord -n && \
        tail -F /var/www/storage/logs/*
```

Comment: Why you need it at build time? It is for building purposes ?

Comment: @jhernandez The composer dumpautoload command fails without the variables being loaded into a specific class. It passes if I manually put in the details, or if I comment out the code, build, uncomment and then run the autoload command from the shell.

Comment: @jhernandez also yes it's for building a docker image, which will eventually be pushed to dockerhub.

Comment: Can you run autoload together with what is the target inside Dockerfile? Like ``CMD command_to_do_autoload && command_which_is_now_starts_container`` ?

Comment: @heroin I'll update the question with the command that runs and starts the container shortly